# DynamoDB query sorted data

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a DynamoDB table and with fields `user_id` and `date`. I want to create an SQL equivelant query `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10` in order to get most recent records of users in batches of 10 records. I'm using ruby aws-sdk

Answer (score 0):

For this `user_id` must be your partition key and `date` must be your sort key.

You can execute 3 [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operations, one for each user. Set `ScanIndexForward` to false, and `Limit` to 10. This will return the 10 most recent records for each user.

If the keys of your table are different, then you can create a global secondary index with the keys you require to ensure the query is efficient.

You can use PartiQL `ExecuteStatement` which will allow you to execute the exact SQL statement that you shared against your table, again provided the keys are like I suggested. You can return up to 50 partition keys on a single request. Ordering will be for each key, no ordering between all items.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to do it in 1 query because the array of the the ids (1,2,3) may grow and to 50 or 100 and also by quering 3 times how can I get the next batch of 10?

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried this but it doesn't recognise `IN`

Comment: Show me what you tried?

Comment: e = Dynamoid.adapter.execute("SELECT * from posts where user_id IN ?", ["dedc28d0-7e55-457a-bc3c-a25eda06ec87"])
/ruby-3.1.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.185.1/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in `call': IN operator must have a left hand argument of type Variable Reference and right hand argument of type Seq with at least one member (Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ValidationException)

Comment: That looks like a syntax error to me: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.select.html#ql-reference.select.syntax